# checking definition of bounded linear function involves operator maps between different spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be two Hilbert spaces. Let $T:K\to H$ be a bounded linear operator. Denote the inner products on $H$ and $K$ by $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_H$, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_K$. Fix any $y\in H$; then the linear mapping 
$$ \Phi: K\to\mathbb{C},\quad\Phi x :=\langle Tx,y\rangle_H$$
defines a bounded functional on the Hilbert space $K$.

Could anyone help with the proof of above claim?
Recall, a functional simply a linear operator $\Phi:H\to \mathbb{C}$.

$\Phi$ is bounded if there exists $K$ such that $|\Phi x|\le K\|x\|,\,\,\forall\,\,x\in H$. So I have
$$|\Phi x|=|\langle Tx,y\rangle_H|\le\cdots$$

Please help.

Comment: Still, your choice of symbols is rather sloppy here. Both $K$ and $H$ have two quite distinct meanings here. It doesn't matter much if you do keep control over it (and this being a small piece of math, it is not that hard), but be careful.

Comment: Hint: Cauchy Schwarz and then the definition of operator norm

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: How do you prove that $y^*\colon H\to {\bf C}$ defined by $y^*(y'):=\langle y',y\rangle$ is bounded? Or, if you know what an adjoint operator is, just notice that $\Phi$ is just $T^*(y^*)$.

Comment: Im sorry I do not understand what you mean. I have not got to the point to understand adjoint operator yet...need a more precise answer.

Comment: Which part do you not understand? What $y^*$ is?

Comment: It would help if you provide a detail answer to my question to get me started. I do not know how to prove your first sentence.

Comment: @math101: Well, that's what you should do first. I will not give any more detailed answer, especially while you're not even showing any effort of your own.

Comment: i deleted my comment for privacy. But I am sorry I do not feel the hint helpful.